# Android. How to correctly position elements in row?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, composable, android-compose-image, android-jetpack-compose-row

I'm trying to position elements in my `Row` like this: text first, immediately followed by an icon, and a second icon that should be nailed to the end (right edge). Here is a visual example of what it should look like:
[image]

And when text very long I need:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
 Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
    ) {
        Row(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
            Text(
                text,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.Top)
            )

                Icon(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 12.dp),
                    painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_circle),
                    contentDescription = ""
                )
        }

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(26.dp)
                .align(Alignment.CenterVertically),
        ) {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
                painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_square),
                contentDescription = null,
            )
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the text can be very long, in which case my first icon (circle) is not displayed. Please help, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Modifier.weight(1f, fill = false)` on `Text` so `Image` is always measured with its own width while text keeps growing. Row and Column measures Composables without Modifier.weight first then divides space between the ones with Modifier.weight.

```
Text(
    text,
    modifier = Modifier
        .align(Alignment.Top)
        .weight(1f, fill = false)
)
```

And it can be tested like this

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun RowTest() {
    var text by remember {
        mutableStateOf("Text text")
    }

    Column {
        SampleComposable(text = text)
        TextField(value = text, onValueChange = { text = it })
    }
}

@Composable
private fun SampleComposable(text: String) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
    ) {
        Row(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
Text(
    text,
    modifier = Modifier
        .align(Alignment.Top)
        .weight(1f, fill = false)
)

            Icon(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 12.dp),
                imageVector = Icons.Default.Circle,
                contentDescription = ""
            )
        }

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(26.dp)
                .align(Alignment.Top),
        ) {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
                imageVector = Icons.Default.Square,
                contentDescription = null,
            )
        }
    }
}
```